# Ordering an SQL query with exceptions

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table of products, and I need to write an SQL query which orders these products alphabetically according to their manufacturer.

i.e.

`SELECT * FROM ProductsTable ORDER BY Manufacturer`

But the complication is that we are trying to promote one particular manufacturer. So all the products for this manufacturer need to come at the top and not be alphabetised with the rest.

```
e.g.

+---------+------------+
|Product  |Manufacturer|
+---------+------------+
|pears    |Jim         |
|apples   |Fred        |
|tomatoes |Adam        |
|oranges  |Bob         |
|bananas  |Fred        |
|grapes   |Carl        |
+---------+------------+

If we are promoting Fred, the query would result in

+---------+------------+
|Product  |Manufacturer|
+---------+------------+
|apples   |Fred        |
|bananas  |Fred        |
|tomatoes |Adam        |
|oranges  |Bob         |
|grapes   |Carl        |
|pears    |Jim         |
+---------+------------+
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Manufacturer = 'Fred' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Ordering
FROM ProductsTable 
ORDER BY Ordering, Manufacturer
```

Comment: But with this, he would have to know what is promoting manufacturer, while writing code. Promoted manufacturer has to be stored in the database, because it is not always Fred, if I understand Urbycoz well.

Comment: @vucetica not at all, for sure the final implementation of that would be "CASE WHEN Manufacturer = @PromotedManufacturer", it would be a query parameter. The value for that param could come for anywhere, but that shouldn't be a problem since off course the Manufacturer being promoted should be stored somewhere. I think is better than having an additional field and mantain it.

Comment: Here is how I see it: when you put @promotedManufacturer parameter, it has to be set from anywhere, like you said, but that "anywhere" is again source code. He can read that parameter from some config file, which would mean that "Fred" is set in the config file, or from the database. To read it from config file is good, but is again kind of "hard coded", because it is not a good thing to change that from some "admin panel", so the right solution would be to store "Fred" in the database. One way to do it (among many), is to put flag next to Fred, Mike and John, which are promoted manufacturers.

Comment: In my case the promoting manufacturer will not change. Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @Firoz Ansari This works brilliantly and is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: And if you wanted to make the exception be the last item on the list, then it would be:-

    SELECT *, CASE WHEN Manufacturer = 'Fred' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS Ordering
FROM ProductsTable 
ORDER BY Ordering, Manufacturer

Answer (score 3):

Next to manufacturer, put a new field: Weight, and give weight 1 to promoting manufacturer, and 0 to others, then write your query:

```
SELECT * FROM ProductsTable ORDER BY Weight, Manufacturer
```

to promote manufacturer Fred, use:

```
UPDATE ProductsTable SET Weight = 0;
UPDATE ProductsTable SET Weight = 1 WHERE Manufacturer='Fred';
```

(it would be good to wrap those two `update` queries into transaction)

Comment: Agreed. There is no good way to get what he needs unless he knows which manufacturer is to be promoted.

Comment: I think adding another column for sort order make sense. This also allow user to maintain this order through UI.

Comment: In my case I do know the promoting manufacturer, and it will not change. Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: In that case this doesn't make sense, but I will leave this answer here in case someone has the same problem, but inside application, not just on a query level. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work based on my experience with Microsoft Access database but I would expect works in some other SQL databases too...

```
SELECT * FROM ProductsTable ORDER BY (Manufacturer='Fred'), Manufacturer;
```